# Grub2 showing two Windows 7 loaders

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I had an issue with Windows 7 and had to reinstall and it overwrote grub.
I used a live disk and boot repair to reinstall grub. However it now shows
two 'Windows 7 Loaders':

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
```

I have not seen this before and wanted to ask for advice such as if this could lead to future problems. I assume the sda1 is the Windows rescue partition but am not sure. I seem to recall that a chainloader is used in grub to boot Windows and so perhaps this is the way it represents it. I do not remember the proper Linux way to interrogate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. It won't lead to future problems just existing. A chainloader is used in grub to boot windows, grub just passes control to the windows bootloader to boot windows. Just use either one to boot into Windows when you need to, and don't touch it. The windows bootloader somehow accidentally installed to two partitions for some reason.

Comment: Didn't know about something like this. If you feel brave enough you could try to "manage" it with gParted.

Comment: Thanks. Windows is crazed when it installs. I just used the first one and had no problem. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Have a great one! On a sidebar, I am so out of practice it just took me 40 minutes to set up a GitHub repo correctly. May have been easier with a GUI program but I always feel more at home (eventually) with the good old command line but need a lot of rust shaken off :)